# 'Import error: cannot import name mysqldb'

Tags: python, mysql

After many issues while working with Python and Windows 7, I finally found a way to install Mysql for python. I did it via `.whl` (wheel), more specifically, this one: https://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/.

It installed succesfully, however, when I try to import it in my project with:

`from MySQLdb import mysqldb` or `from MySQLdb import mysql`, I get this error in Git Bash for any variant that I've tried:

`ImportError: cannot import name MySQLdb`

I can't seem to locate the issue. Any idea would be highly beneficial!

Comment: What Python version are you using?

Comment: It is Python 2.7.14

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A little bit more fresh MySQL-python can be downloaded from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/1.2.5

The import is just `import MySQLdb`.

For Python 2.7 and 3.3+ use [mysqlclient](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysqlclient) or [PyMySQL](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyMySQL).

PyMySQL can be installed as a drop-in replacement for MySQL-python:

```
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
import MySQLdb
```

Comment: Thanks, will try this one as well. My initial issue was solved when I just used 'import MySQLdb' to import the module.